# jQuery/javascript for a dynamic left navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date

I'm trying to put together a script that will generate markup that jQuery UI will accept to make an accordion, like below.

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>2012</h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2012&month=10">October</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2012&month=9">September</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2012&month=8">August</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2012&month=7">July</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2012&month=6">June</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2012&month=5">May</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2012&month=4">April</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2012&month=3">March</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2012&month=2">February</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2012&month=1">January</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>2011</h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2011&month=12>December</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2011&month=11>November</a></li> 
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2011&month=10">October</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2011&month=9">September</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2011&month=8">August</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2011&month=7">July</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2011&month=6">June</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2011&month=5">May</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2011&month=4">April</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2011&month=3">March</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2011&month=2">February</a></li>
        <li><a href="somepage.html?year=2011&month=1">January</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It should output the year and the current and past months all the way back to 2007.  In order to create that type of markup, what would I need to do? Pseudo code:

```
var d = new Date();
var yr = Number(d.getFullYear());
for (var i = 2006, i < yr, i++)
{
  //create a H3, div, and a ul
  var mo = d.getMonth();
  //some other for loop on the month to create the li items
  //how to handle date display names?
}
```

Dates in jQuery/Javascript have always been an Achilles heel of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?? try **DEMO** : [answer demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yosafatade/yW4SL/2/) if yes, so you have to learn more to improve your logic :) try to learn how jquery `append()` , accommodate to temporary variable, and the pattern of html

Comment: That's helpful and will get me on my way to doing what I need. I know about append and the like, that's how I was going to get the html on the page, or by creating an array of objects and using a template.

Comment: This wasn't exactly *the* answer, but it gets me most of the way there. Tweaked some of the for loops to do what I wanted it to.

Comment: that's just an example bro..you can make your way to reach your goal. what you have to do is exercise more :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/jjQkX/1/)

```
var div = $("<div>").attr("id", "accordion");
month = [];
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
var d = new Date();
var yr = Number(d.getFullYear());
for (i = yr; i > 2006; i--) {
    var m = $("<ul>");
    for (j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
        m.append(
        $("<a>").attr("href", "somepage.html?year=" + i + "&month=" + j).text(month[j - 1]));
    }
    div.append(
    $("<h3>").text(i), m);
}
$(elementToAppendTo).append(div);​
```